# Unleveled vs Leveled RF Power

Tags: power, rf

I'm reading over a manual for a RF generator and I've come across the terms leveled and unleveled RF power. I'm curious what the difference is between leveled RF power and unleveled RF power.

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, a (RF) signal generator that has a "levelled" output means that the output level remains constant as the frequency changes.  The generator contains active circuitry (AGC) that adjusts the output level so as to keep it constant.

An "unlevelled" generator does not have such circuitry and the output level changes with frequency.  This output level variation can be quite significant.